# Filtering a dataframe based on a list and then saving each dataframe based on said filter. Is creating a function or for loop the way to go?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I'm doing topic modeling on different categories within my dataset and before I do that I need to split the data into different dataframes based on the category so that I can then cast each one of them to a document-term matrix. From the little I know about for loops I have the following. The part I get stuck is that I need an output for each item in the list.

```
category = c("a",
         "b",
         "c",
         "d",
         "e",
         "f",
         "g",
         "h",
         "i",
         "j")

for (i in category) {

#Subset to test topic model
someDataFrame = anotherDataFrame %>%
  filter(colVariable == i) %>% #here is the column of interest in the dataframe
  select(ID, Word) %>%
  group_by(ID, Word) %>%
  count()

newDataFrame_i = someDataFrame %>% #here's where I'd like to export to individual dataframes
  cast_dtm(ID, Word, n) #in order to do topic modeling, you have to build a document-term matrix 


}
```

Like I said before, I'm expecting a dataframe for each item in the list, however, I keep getting `Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass) : assignment of an object of class “numeric” is not valid for @‘Dim’ in an object of class “dgTMatrix”; is(value, "integer") is not TRUE`.

I've done this using one value (hard-coded, say "a") and get the result I'm looking for so I know my for loop is off.

Solution:

```
filter_and_cast <- function(df, category){
  df %>%
  filter(colVariable == i) %>% #here is the column of interest in the dataframe
  select(ID, Word) %>%
  group_by(ID, Word) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  cast_dm(ID, Word, n)
}

for (i in category) {
  cast = paste("filterCast", i, sep = "_")
  try(assign(cast, filter_and_cast(aDataFrame, i)))
}
```

Thanks to the contributors, I was finally able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve the problem using the **assign()** function which enables the creation of objects passing the name and the values.

Something like:

```
ObjectName = paste(("newDataFrame", i, sep = "_")
assign(ObjectName, newDataFrame_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to save the intermediate outputs into an object

```
category = c("a",
         "b",
         "c",
         "d",
         "e",
         "f",
         "g",
         "h",
         "i",
         "j")
out <-list()
for (i in category) {

#Subset to test topic model
someDataFrame = anotherDataFrame %>%
  filter(colVariable == i) %>% #here is the column of interest in the dataframe
  select(ID, Word) %>%
  group_by(ID, Word) %>%
  count()

out[[i]] = someDataFrame %>% #here's where I'd like to export to individual dataframes
  cast_dtm(ID, Word, n) #in order to do topic modeling, you have to build a document-term matrix 


}
```

Or on the more R-esque style

```
filter_and_cast <- function(df, category){
filter(colVariable == i) %>% #here is the column of interest in the dataframe
  select(ID, Word) %>%
  group_by(ID, Word) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  cast_dm(ID, Word, n)
}
```

Then you could do something like

```
map(category, filter_and_cast, df = anotherDataFrame )
```